# Creating JButton object array

Tags: java, swing

I wish to generate a chess board(8 X 8) using an object array of JButton .However as a basic step towards it the program below should place ten JButtons one below the other(10 X 1). But the in the output it shows only two buttons(2 X1).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Abcd extends JFrame
{

JButton b[]=new JButton[10];

Abcd()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(500, 500);

    int x=0,y=0;

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
      b[i] = new JButton();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
       b[i].setBounds(x,y,50,50);
       b[i].setVisible(true);
       add(b[i]);
       y=+50;
    }
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Abcd();
}
}
```

Comment: Use the appropriate layout manager. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: `setLayout(null);` Do not set the LayoutManager to `null`. Instead learn how to use LayoutManagers and find the correct one for what you want.

Comment: Is it really necessary to not use setLayout(null)?Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Did you read the link that JB Nizet gave?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes that link solved the problem!